# ionic2 dynamic ion-select ..., get selected value in html

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

How to access selected choice in dynamically created ionic list ionic2 ?

This is part of my .ts file where routeArr is my array , in which i am retrieving data from firebase-

```
this.routeList.subscribe(snapshots => {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        var valueToPush = new Array();
        valueToPush[0] = snapshot.key;
        valueToPush[1] = snapshot.val();
        this.routeArr.push(valueToPush);
        console.log(this.routeArr[i]);
        console.log("Array Length = ",this.routeArr.length); // See the length of the array growing
        i=i+1; 
    });
   });
```

This is part of my HTML file where i am displaying radio buttons dynamically

```
<ion-item> 
        <ion-label floating>Trip</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="routeArr">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let route of routeArr" value="{{route[0]}}">{{route[0]}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
```

Comment: Where's the radio buttons? ;)

Comment: Sorry,that's ion-select

Comment: Okay, where do you want to access this this value? What is not working to be more precise.